# キーワードに該当する場所のリストを返す無料のAPIはありますか？

Tags: api

キーワードを入力したら、キーワードに該当する場所のリストを表示したいです。

無料でキーワードに該当する場所のリストを返すREST APIがあれば教えていただきたいです。
なお、APIのパラメータとして、緯度・経度は指定不要で、キーワードを指定するAPIだと使いやすいです。
やりたいことは、ユーザがAと入力したら秋田や青森などの場所名をリストで表示する機能を作りたいです。

環境は、ios10で、言語はswift4です。

Comment: 求めているのは位置情報ではなく、あくまで「地名」ですか？ / `ユーザがAと入力したら秋田や青森など` は、読み仮名で検索するという意味？ / 「東京タワー」など一意な地名であればいいですが、単に「東京」と検索した場合はどのような結果が返ることを想定していますか？

Answer (score 1):

https://teratail.com/questions/217501
にて「逆ジオコーディング」というキーワードをもらってベストアンサーマーク済み、つまり解決済みのようです。

Comment: cubick様、774RR様回答ありがとうございます。ご指摘のとおりTERATAILで解決しました。